# Set default value in SelectList in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I have a `SelectList`:

```
ViewData["Agency"] = new SelectList(db.Agencies.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(_ => _.AgencyID), "AgencyId", "Name");
```

I need to select default value, I try this:

```
 ViewData["Agency"] = new SelectList(db.Agencies.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(_ => _.AgencyID), "AgencyId", "Name",999);
```

And this:

```
var valueSelected = db.Agencies.AsNoTracking().Where(_=>_.AgencyId == 999).First();

ViewData["Agency"] = new SelectList(db.Agencies.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(_ => _.AgencyID), "AgencyId", "Name",valueSelected );
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: You have not shown your view. Assuming you using `@Html.DropDowmListFor(m => m.someProperty, (SelectList)ViewData["Agency"])` then you need to set the value of `someProperty` - if your binding to a property, its the value of the property that determines the selected option (trying the set the `selectedValue` parameter is just ignored by the html helper)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `AgentID`to `SelectList` constructor for setting as selected by default:

```
 var valueSelected = db.Agencies.AsNoTracking().Where(=>.AgencyId == 999).First();
```

and Now in SelectList:

```
ViewData["Agency"] = new SelectList(db.Agencies.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(_ => _.AgencyID), "AgencyId", "Name",valueSelected.AgencyId );
```

Comment: can you reproduce in dotnetfiddle

Comment: valueSelected.AgencyId = 999 so this creates the same thing as the second attempt in the op's question that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()`.

```
var valueSelected = db
    .Agencies.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(_=>_.AgencyId == 999)
    .FirstOrDefault();

ViewData["Agency"] = new SelectList(db.Agencies.AsNoTracking()
    .OrderBy(_ => _.AgencyID), "AgencyId", "Name",valueSelected );
```